# Count rows returned from a GROUP BY

Tags: mysql

I currently have this query

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM  `applications` 
    WHERE approved =0
    GROUP BY user_id
    ORDER BY  `applications`.`user_id` ASC
```

Which ( in my case ) returns two rows like this

```
COUNT(*)
1
1
```

But the count isn't counting all the whole query, just one row at a time. How would I get this desired output?

```
COUNT(*)
2
```

**EDIT**

The reason for the group by is so that users that have more than one application only counts as 1. For example

John has 4 applications
Tracy has 1 applications
Fred has 2 applications

Total count returned is 3.

Comment: Then why do you have a GROUP BY? This says `give me the count for each group`. If you just want a total count, simplify. Also the `ORDER BY` makes absolutely no sense. That column isn't even returned in the output...

Comment: Because I don't want to count multiple applications by a user.

Comment: So `COUNT(DISTINCT user_id)`.

Comment: Yup, just waiting till I can accept an answer below. But thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will return 2:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT user_id)
FROM applications
WHERE approved = 0
```

It's hard to tell whether this is what you want or DVK's answer is right, because they both return the same answer when each user has 1 matching row.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the total count of rows, remove the "group by" and "order" (the first one is the problem, the second one simply un-necessary since there's no ordering a single row).

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM  `applications` 
WHERE approved =0
```

If you want the total count of user_ids, switch "count(*)" to "count(distinct user_id)"

---

The reason you get 2 rows now is because GROUP BY clause print counts per-group. You can see that if you add "user_id" to your select:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) , user_id
    FROM  `applications` 
    WHERE approved =0
    GROUP BY user_id
    ORDER BY  `applications`.`user_id` ASC
```

Which will returns two rows like this

```
COUNT(*) , user_id
1        , user1
1        , user2
```